# Memory efficient way to initialize a String to be reused inside a loop

Tags: java, string

I'm using a couple of Strings in my code that are going to be reused within a loop and I'm wondering what would be the best way to initialize the String variables to improve memory usage:

```
// Just for sample purposes I will declare a Map, but the same thing
// applies for an ArrayList, Database Set, etc. You get the point.
Map<String, String> sampleMap = getMap();
int mapSize = sampleMap.size();

// String initialization
String a;
String b = new String();
String c = "";

for(int i = 0; i < mapSize; i++){
    a = sampleMap.get(i);
    b = someFunc(a);
    c = anotherFunc(a);
    // Do stuff with all the Strings
}
```

After the loop, the Strings are no longer used.

Comment: @shekharsuman: Your comment is not true. The variable `a` is initialized in the loop before it is read.

Comment: @NayukiMinase-Sorry, didn't look carefully. Removed.

Comment: What exactly is your concern with memory usage? You're using some strings, then disposing them. All the strings reside in the map, don't they?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Just broke this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot optimize the initialization or memory usage of strings in your snippet of code, for several reasons:

1. Java strings are immutable - you cannot change the characters inside a string, but you can point to a new string.
2. In your loop, the called function (such as `aFunc()` or `get()`) is the one responsible for allocating the string, not the loop.

For advanced programmers: If you do want to optimize the memory usage of strings, you would need to use a StringBuffer/StringBuilder or raw character array and pass them around various function calls. You'd create the buffer before the loop, and pass it into the `get()` and other functions, so that they use this one buffer instead of allocating and returning their own.

Answer (score 9):

Reduce the scope of your variables to restrict them to where they are used:

```
// Just for sample purposes I will declare a Map, but the same thing
// applies for an ArrayList, Database Set, etc. You get the point.
Map<String, String> sampleMap = getMap();
int mapSize = sampleMap.size();

for(int i = 0; i < mapSize; i++){
    String a = aFunc();
    String b = sampleMap.get(i);
    String c = anotherFunc();
    // Do stuff with the Strings
}
```

There is no performance benefit of declaring the variables outside the loop.

Comment: There is also no performance/efficiency benefit of declaring within the loop.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: True - but there's a readability benefit, unless either a) previous values should be reused between iterations; b) the final values need to be preserved after the loop.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sure, but OP's question was about "improving memory usage"

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: And the answer to that part is in the bottom part, effectively.

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh, I see a point there. OP may have imagined that those declarations make a difference. Could be. Maybe he's also confusing "initialization" with "declaration".

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: I've added an answer to clarify that aspect myself.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't add a String with another, the Strings are already in memory (because they are immutable), I think this will have no impact on your memory footprint.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using a couple of Strings in my code that are going to be reused within a loop

No, you're not. You're using a few string *variables* that are going to be reused within the loop. The actual strings aren't. Here's the body of the loop that you posted:

```
a = sampleMap.get(i);
b = someFunc(a);
c = anotherFunc(a);
```

The values of `a`, `b` and `c` from previous iterations (or the values before the first iteration) are completely ignored within the body of the loop. Any value you assign before the loop is at best irrelevant, and at worst distracting and/or costly in efficiency. (If you use an empty string, and for some reason none of the rest of the VM ever uses an empty string, you're introducing one for no reason.)

I would recommend following 6ton's advice, and introducing the variables within the loop to start with, for the sake of readability - it won't affect your memory efficiency.